# Unity3D v5 error while compiling

Tags: c#, exception, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

So this error has been bugging me for the whole day now.
It just simply won't compile my Project. I have tried to compile for web-player/standalone/etc, but its giving me error.

This is the Error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.PluginImporter+<GetImporters>c__AnonStoreyC.<>m__E (UnityEditor.PluginImporter imp) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/PluginImporterBindings.gen.cs:104)
System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateWhereIterator>c__Iterator1D`1[UnityEditor.PluginImporter].MoveNext ()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEditor.PluginImporter].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:128)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEditor.PluginImporter]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:65)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[PluginImporter] (IEnumerable`1 source)
UnityEditor.PluginImporter.GetImporters (System.String platformName) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/PluginImporterBindings.gen.cs:103)
UnityEditor.PluginImporter.GetImporters (BuildTarget platform) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/PluginImporterBindings.gen.cs:111)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:129)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:198)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

and

```
 Error building Player: Extracting referenced dlls failed.`
```

When I hit Play though, the Project works flawlessly. Also I have no idea why is it telling me about "PluginImporter" since I'm not using any plugins.

I have tried setting my Project Api Compability to NET 2.0, but still no dice.

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an error in a plugin/asset that is not correctly installed.